# Clojure - Make first + filter lazy

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

I am learning clojure. While solving one of the problem, I had to use `first` + `filter`. I noted that the filter is running unnecessarily for all the inputs.
How can I make the `filter` to run lazily so that it need not apply the predicate for the whole input.

The below is an example showing that it is not lazy,

```
(defn filter-even
  [n]
  (println n)
  (= (mod n 2) 0))

(first (filter filter-even (range 1 4)))
```

The above code prints

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

Whereas it need not go beyond `2`. How can we make it lazy?

Comment: You might consider using `some` instead of `(first (filter ...))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because `range` is a chunked sequence:

```
(chunked-seq? (range 1))
=> true
```

And it will actually take the first 32 elements if available:

```
(first (filter filter-even (range 1 100)))
1
2
. . .
30
31
32
=> 2
```

[This overview](http://www.tianxiangxiong.com/2016/11/05/chunking-and-laziness-in-clojure.html) shows an `unchunk` function that prevents this from happening. Unfortunately, it isn't standard:

```
(defn unchunk [s]
  (when (seq s)
    (lazy-seq
      (cons (first s)
            (unchunk (next s))))))

(first (filter filter-even (unchunk (range 1 100))))
2
=> 2
```

Or, you could apply `list` to it since lists aren't chunked:

```
(first (filter filter-even (apply list (range 1 100))))
2
=> 2
```

But then obviously, the entire collection needs to be realized pre-filtering.

This honestly isn't something that I've ever been too concerned about though. The filtering function usually isn't *too* expensive, and 32 element chunks aren't *that* big in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Also see: https://stuartsierra.com/2015/08/25/clojure-donts-lazy-effects

Comment: Yes, just added it as extra information around this topic.